# Shared folder syntax

Tags: windows, command-line

Please explain the differences between `net use` commands syntax and what each command does.

```
net use \\techdata
net use \\techdata\softwares
```

I see that both command completed successfully. However, I don't understand the functional details and effect of each.

As per above example, I connected to Shared folder "Softwares". However, its not showing contents of "Softwares".

Answer (score 0):

The above examples don't really have any kind of difference. One refers to a specific share while the other refers to a computer.

The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) gives the following explanation for the command itself:

> Connects a computer to or disconnects a computer from a shared resource, or displays information about computer connections. The command also controls persistent net connections. Used without parameters, net use retrieves a list of network connections.

This documentation also has some more indepth information about various parameters.

What you're doing with the two examples you gave is to tell your Windows installation to use your current credentials to access those shares. Usually you'd either include a drive letter to map a share as a drive and/or include credentials to use different credentials to establish the connection.

Comment: So net use \\techdata\softwares is only used to establish network connection on share not for viewing its contents. As opposed to view shared folder contents net use Z: \\techdata\softwares via drive mapping.

Comment: Well you could just type `\\techdata\softwares` into the bar of your explorer window or whatever file explorer you're using to view the contents of that share.

Comment: Let me ask in a simple way:

What will be the difference between adding drive letter or omitting letter in the following command examples.

net use E: \\techdata\dml   

net use \\techdata\dml

Does it mean that omitting drive letter will just only allow establishing the network connection and will not allow to view contents on shared resource located on server?

Please explain and correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The only difference would be whenever you get a mapping to `E:\` or not. It's to decide which credentials to use to access that path. Which operations would work an the actual viewing/reading/writing etc. would be issued by the program that does that. it would use that path and in the Background Windows should take care of the necessary communication. After all such a path is most likely either a SMB or CIFS share and you don't want to re-implement that stuff every time.